# Crash in std::locale::operator=(std::locale const&) on AIX

Tags: c++, gcc, rpm, aix

I am a bit new to AIX and stuck up with a weird issue. I have two AIX machine and my C++ application is running on one and crashing on the other.

When I checked packages installed (rpm -qa), I observed one difference, for 1st  machine all the rpm's are ending with .ppc extension and for 2nd it's not. My cpp app is perfectly running on 2nd  machine.

I suspect this can be a cause for this issue but not sure.

PS: Showing the difference between two.
[image: Difference between two]

Stack Trace:

```
    Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0xd0bded2c in std::locale::operator=(std::locale const&) () from /opt/freeware/lib/libstdc++.a(libstdc++.so.6)
(gdb) bt
#0  0xd0bded2c in std::locale::operator=(std::locale const&) () from /opt/freeware/lib/libstdc++.a(libstdc++.so.6)
#1  0xd0bdeee0 in std::ios_base::_M_init() () from /opt/freeware/lib/libstdc++.a(libstdc++.so.6)
#2  0xd0bdede4 in std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::init () from /opt/freeware/lib/libstdc++.a(libstdc++.so.6)
#3  0x100b618c in Logging::Logging (this=0x20086438, filename=..., level=4) at Logging.cpp:404
#4  0x1005d96c in main (argc=<error reading variable>, argv=<error reading variable>) at  _start_ :141
warning: (Internal error: pc 0x100001e3 in read in psymtab, but not in symtab.)

warning: (Internal error: pc 0x100001e4 in read in psymtab, but not in symtab.)
```

Code Snapshot:

```
string logFile = "test.txt"
Logging* logger = new Logging(logFile,4);

// Logging Constructor     
Logging::Logging(const string &filename,loglevel): logfilename(filename),level(loglevel) {
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information about the actual crash. Like a stacktrace (from the core dump from a debugger, etc.).

Comment: @OP Maybe the locale you want to use is not installed on one of the computers. Eg: `bash -c 'LC_ALL=hu_HU.UTF-8'` results `setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (hu_HU.UTF-8)` indicating that `bos.loc.utf.HU_HU` isn't installed.

Comment: I'm catching the same crash on [`gcc119`](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/CompileFarm) on the GCC compile farm. That's an updated compiler at `/opt/freeware`. GCC 4.8 (or was it 4.9) at `/usr/bin` did not have the crash. Setting `LC_ALL=C` does not help the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same issue and was able to fix so by disabling optimization flags (like -O2) at makefile for the g++ compiler. My makefile contained

`CC = g++
CC_FLAGS = -g3 -ggdb -Wall -std=c++11 -DDEBUG -pthread -O2`

Where the backtrace from gdb shown
[std::locale::operator=(std::locale const&) ()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeIUA.png)

This wasn't occouring anymore without flags "-O2"

`CC = g++
CC_FLAGS = -Wall -std=c++11 -DDEBUG -pthread`