# Avoid -blibpath when linking an Autotools project on AIX

Tags: linker, aix, autotools, autoconf, powerpc

We are catching a segfault on a project built using Autotools on AIX. According to gdb it is dying in startup code. The same project built with a GNUmakefile is fine. A related problem is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43490185/608639).

Autotools adds some unusual linker flags and we are fairly certain it is the root cause of the problem. The Autotools generated Makefile is online [here](https://pastebin.com/s9fCVb1k).

And:

```
libtool: link: g++ -pthread -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -pipe -g -O2 -pt
hread -o .libs/cryptestcwd cryptestcwd-test.o ...
yptestcwd-dlltest.o cryptestcwd-fipsalgt.o cryptestcwd-adhoc.o  -L./.libs -lcryp
topp -L/opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.2.0.0/7.2.0 -lstdc++ -lm -pthread
-Wl,-blibpath:/usr/local/lib:/opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.2.0.0/7.2.0:
/opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.2.0.0/7.2.0:/opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc
-ibm-aix7.2.0.0/7.2.0/../../..:/usr/lib:/lib
```

The flags do not come from the environment or our `configure.ac`:

```
-bash-4.4$ echo $LDFLAGS
-bash-4.4$ echo $LDLIBS $LIBS
-bash-4.4$
```

And the `AM_CXXFLAGS` and `AM_LDFLAGS` we add:

```
AM_CXXFLAGS:  -pthread -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections
AM_LDFLAGS:  -pthread -Wl,--demangle
```

I've tried to `make LDFLAGS=""` and override the Autotools flags but the same flags are added.

My first question is, how are they overriding our `LDFLAGS`? GNU makefiles don't work that way. GNU always allows a user to override a makefile's flags.

My second question is, how do we stop Autotools from adding the unwanted flags during the link phase?

---

Here is our [`configure.ac`](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-autotools). Here is the summary of options we add after running a vanilla `./configure`:

```
Auto-configuration complete. A summary of options are below. If
something looks wrong then please modify config.h and please report
it at http://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-autotools.

   Build triplet: powerpc-ibm-aix7.2.0.0
 Compiler target: powerpc-ibm-aix7.2.0.0
Compiler version: g++ (GCC) 7.2.0

Static library: yes
Shared library: yes

CRYPTOPP_PPC_FLAG: -mcpu=power8 -maltivec
CRYPTOPP_CHAM_FLAG: -mcpu=power7 -maltivec
CRYPTOPP_CRC_FLAG: -mcpu=power8 -maltivec
CRYPTOPP_LEA_FLAG: -mcpu=power7 -maltivec
CRYPTOPP_GCM_FLAG: -mcpu=power8 -maltivec
CRYPTOPP_AES_FLAG: -mcpu=power8 -maltivec
CRYPTOPP_SHA_FLAG: -mcpu=power8 -maltivec
CRYPTOPP_SIMECK_FLAG: -mcpu=power7 -maltivec
CRYPTOPP_SIMON_FLAG: -mcpu=power7 -maltivec
CRYPTOPP_SPECK_FLAG: -mcpu=power7 -maltivec
CRYPTOPP_SM4_FLAG: -mcpu=power7 -maltivec

Automake flags (can be overridden by user flags):
AM_CXXFLAGS:  -pthread -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections
AM_LDFLAGS:  -pthread -Wl,--demangle

User flags (overrides Automake flags on conflict):
CXXFLAGS: -g -O2
LDFLAGS:
```

Comment: Hi, what are the _autotool commands_ you used?

Comment: @Lorinczy - I added additional information with the Autotools command and the flags we added through `AM_CXXFLAGS` and `AM_LDFLAGS`.

Comment: @Lorinczy - Do you have any ideas? I'm stumped where these extra flags are coming from and why I can't override them.

Comment: You should find out where this LDFLAGS comes from, as it is plain wrong. Is the whole program downloadable from somewhere?

Comment: @Lorinczy - Yes, the Autotools front-end is available as a separate project at [Crypto++ | Autotools](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-autotools).

Answer (score 2):

> My first question is, how are they overriding our LDFLAGS? GNU
>   makefiles don't work that way. GNU always allow a user to override a
>   makefile's flags.

The Autotools are not overriding your `LDFLAGS`.  It is not within their power to do so, and it is [an explicit design philosophy of the Autotools](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/User-Variables.html) that they do not override the decisions of the person building the project.

However, `LDFLAGS` is not the only source of link options.  The compiler flags are added too, and in particular, libraries to link in shouldn't be included in `LDFLAGS` (or `AM_LDFLAGS` or `mytarget_LDFLAGS`) at all, because those variables (the first and exactly one of the latter two) are expanded before the list of objects to link.

But above and beyond all that, `libtool` adds flags that it thinks are appropriate, and that's where the `-Wl,-blibpath` is coming from in your case.

> My second question is, how do we stop Autotools from adding the
>   unwanted flags during the link phase?

Not easily, I'm afraid.  Your best option is probably to modify the in-project copy of the `libtool` shell script to suppress it.  This is analogous to Fedora's packaging guidelines for suppressing generation of `rpath` entries in ELF binaries.

You might also want to consider digging deeper into why that option causes trouble for you.  It sets a run-time shared library search path (again like rpath), and if you get different behavior with and without then that implies that different libraries are getting dynamically linked in those two cases.  It looks like `libtool` chooses the path it does based on the compile-time library search path, and if so then it should concern you that the libraries you are linking against do not successfully support the program at runtime.

Comment: Thanks John. Digging deeper to determine what is wrong is a non-starter. Symbols are not installed and the debugger only works part of the time. In fact I can't even restart the program under the debugger. Plus, I can't fix what is wrong in the startup code. That is someone else's code.